# Need to change a access denied page's message displayed

Tags: drupal, authentication, message

We have a check out page in my drupal site. When users are not logged in and if users proceed to checkout, a message is displayed, i need to change that message text.

Comment: Guys if you come across problem with changing a text please refer
http://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides..As this might help many ...

Comment: Did you know you can change the default 403 page here? admin/settings/error-reporting

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the [CustomError](http://drupal.org/project/customerror) module does what you're looking for.